# Nested bullets with code blocks in markdown for Github

Tags: github, markdown

I have the following text inside a Markdown file:

````
- In order to free :

    - Items no rateados por exp: 

```javascript
db.items.find({"detail.rc": {$lt: 20}, "dst": "v"}).count()
db.items.find({"detail.rc": {$lt: 20}, "dst": "b"}).count()
```

    - Items no rateados por exp y sin rat:

```javascript
db.items.find({"detail.rc": {$lt: 20}, "dst": "v"}).count()
db.items.find({"detail.rc": {$lt: 20}, "dst": "b"}).count()
```
````

It looks like the image below when parsed, where green arrows suppose to have same level bullet, but the second one is highlighted. I just want it as the first one. How can I do that?

[image: Parsed image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You just need to indent your code blocks with 4 spaces.